# Is there a method to get the module/action a URL refers to?

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, reverse

In symfony, is there a method that I can use which does a reverse lookup on my routes to determine the module and action a URL points to?

Say, something like:

```
get_module("http://host/cars/list"); // ("cars")
get_action("http://host/frontend_dev.php/cars/list"); // ("list")
```

Bear in mind, I don't want to perform simple string-hacking to do this as there may be mappings that are not quite so obvious:

```
get_module("/");  // (What this returns is entirely dependent on the configured routes.)
```

Thanks!

Comment: While in #symfony on freenode, I noted that symfony basically does this already when fulfilling requests! It appears as though there's simply no best practise way of getting this information yourself.  Maybe something like $context->getRouting()->match('url') ?

Comment: I have opened the following ticket in regards to this issue: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sfRouting class to match URLs.  This is part of the sfContext object.  Your code (in an action) would look like this:

```
public function executeSomeAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  if($params = $this->getContext()->getRouting()->parse('/blog'))
  {
     $module = $params['module']; // blog
     $action = $params['action']; // index
     $route  = $params['_sf_route'] // routing instance (for fun)
  }
  else
  {
     // your URL did not match
  }
}
```

Comment: While this isn't 100% my solution, this is pretty close and likely will be as close as one can get until they make something in the symfony API.